# Transforming a history table to an "ownership" table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Apologies for the wording, I can't really find another way to phrase it.

I have a history table like so:

```
id  date         from_id   to_id
1   2010-01-01   A         B
1   2010-01-02   B         C
1   2010-01-03   C         D
2   2010-01-04   A         B
2   2010-01-05   B         X
2   2010-01-06   X         Y
```

This indicates that the object with id "1" was transferred from A->B->C->D and "2" was transferred as A->B->X->Y, at the respective dates.

Now, I want to transform this table to an "ownership history" table as follows:

```
id  date_from   date_to     owner_id
1   NULL        2010-01-01  A
1   2010-01-01  2010-01-02  B
1   2010-01-02  2010-01-03  C
1   2010-01-03  2010-01-04  D
1   2010-01-04  NULL        D
2   NULL        2010-01-04  A
2   2010-01-04  2010-01-05  B
2   2010-01-05  2010-01-06  X
2   2010-01-06  NULL        Y
```

Is there an efficient way to do this, using MySQL?

As of now I've got something along the lines of the following, though it's very, very slow:

```
select id, from_id as owner_id, date as date_from, (select date from table where from_id = h.to_id and id = h.id and date > h.date limit 1) as date_to from table h;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do most of the work using a `left join`:

```
select h.id, h.date as date_from, h2.date as date_to, h2.to_id
from history h left join
     history h2
     on h.id = h2.id and h.to_id = h2.from_id;
```

This just leaves off the initial record for each id.  For that, use `union all`:

```
select h.id, h.date as date_from, h2.date as date_to, h2.to_id
from history h left join
     history h2
     on h.id = h2.id and h.to_id = h2.from_id
union all
select h.id, NULL as date_from, h.date as date_to, h.id
from history h;
```